# Clarifai: "Malformed or invalid request"

Tags: python, clarifai

I have the following Python code that makes a POST request to Clarifai's demographics endpoint:

```
import requests
import pprint

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Key MY_KEY",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": "https://samples.clarifai.com/demographics.jpg"}}}]}

proxies = {
    "http": "MY_HTTP_PROXY", 
    "https": "MY_HTTPS_PROXY"
}

response = requests.post('https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/c0c0ac362b03416da06ab3fa36fb58e3/outputs', headers=headers, data=data, proxies=proxies, verify=False)

pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Note that I've replaced my real api key and proxies with MY_KEY, MY_HTTP_PROXY, and MY_HTTPS_PROXY respectively.

Does anyone experienced with Clarifai know what I'm doing wrong? I saw an [example of working](https://community.clarifai.com/t/simple-python-requests-example-help-request/932/2) code posted on Clarifai's own forum, but I can't see any major differences between the working code and mine.

Comment: Can you post the full error output here? That should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the data passed to json.

```
import requests
import pprint
import json

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Key MY_KEY",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": "https://samples.clarifai.com/demographics.jpg"}}}]}

json_data = json.dumps(data)

proxies = {
    "http": "MY_HTTP_PROXY", 
    "https": "MY_HTTPS_PROXY"
}

response = requests.post('https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/c0c0ac362b03416da06ab3fa36fb58e3/outputs', headers=headers, data=json_data, proxies=proxies, verify=False)

pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Answer (score -1):

Needed quotes around the data variable

```
'data = {"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": "https://samples.clarifai.com/demographics.jpg"}}}]}'
```

Comment: ``data`` is the variable that contains the POST payload. It has to be assignment with quotes.